# Rownumbers on multi-page tables

Tags: tables, line-numbering

Im trying to have automatic rownumbers on a multi-page table reset on a page-break.
So far I got this, but I dont know, why the counter does not reset:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,ltablex}
\newcounter{rownumber}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\stepcounter{rownumber}\arabic{rownumber}}c|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Rownumber\setcounter{rownumber}{0}}&Data\\\hline
    \endhead
    &Ok\newline\lipsum[1]\\\hline
    &Ok\newline\lipsum[2]\\\hline
    &Ok\newline\lipsum[3]\\\hline
    &Ok\\\hline
    &Ok\\\hline
    &Should be 1\\\hline
    &Should be 2\\\hline
    &\ldots\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: longtable uses tex's asynchronous page breaking routines, so typically many rows, or with `tabularx` as you have there, the entire table, has been set _before_ any page breaking happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DavidCarlisle
So the headlines are beeing added afterwards and there is no way to reset the counter (at the right time) and other table-packages work the same way?

Comment: @Visacer no in fact other table packages do not work the same way superatb/xtab  page break by counting rows witin the macros and making a new tabular on each page, so thety are probably a better starting point

Comment: You can use the aux file and two runs.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196033/how-do-i-test-for-a-new-page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks I got it working with xtab, but apparently I connot use the X columntype, which is more important to me.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, I will have a look at that