# Extension of `rotating` package to set PDF rotation

Tags: xetex, luatex, rotating

I am trying to extend the `rotating` package to also show the respective pages properly rotated in the PDF output by setting the PDF page attribute `/Rotate`. I have a working version for XeLaTeX, however, I don't manage to get this done for LuaLaTeX. Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\ifLuaTeX
    \edef\pdfpageattr{\pdfvariable pageattr}
\fi

\makeatletter
    \def\@PDFrot#1{%
        \ifXeTeX%
            \special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate #1>>}%
        \fi%
        \ifLuaTeX%
            \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate #1}%
            \afterpage{\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}}%
        \fi%
    }

    \patchcmd{\@xrotfloat}%
        {\begin{minipage}\textheight}%
        {\begin{minipage}\textheight\@PDFrot{90}}%
        {}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-10]

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        Test
        \caption{Just an example figure.}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

    \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

When compiling this MWE with XeLaTeX, one will get the desired behavior: The float page with the `sidewaysfigure` contents (page 3) is properly rotated in the PDF output. But when compiled with LuaLaTeX, also page 2 will be rotated, too, which is not desired.

---

[image: Desired PDF page orientations when compiled with XeLaTeX.]
Desired PDF page orientations when compiled with XeLaTeX.

---

[image: Wrong PDF page orientation of page 2 when compiled with LuaLaTeX.]
Wrong PDF page orientation of page 2 when compiled with LuaLaTeX.

---

I think this is because the definition of the `sidewaysfigure` contents (together with setting the PDF attribute) will already be evaluated on page 2, where the content would appear if it would not be a float. I've found no way of circumventing this problem and would be glad for any idea.

**N.B.:** The MWE is just a reduced example, which does not properly take the orientation of the page based on its page number (even/odd) into account. I eliminated these code parts for the sake of easier understanding of the MWE.

Comment: afterpage doesn't work. You need a label/ref system to identify the page and add/remove the page attribute. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472608/2388

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472608/2388) provided in comment by Ulrike Fischer, I developed the following patch which also takes even/odd pages into account:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\makeatletter
    \ifXeTeX%
        \patchcmd{\@xrotfloat}%
            {\begin{minipage}\textheight}%
            {%
                \begin{minipage}\textheight%
                \ifnumodd{\thepage}%
                    {\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate 90>>}}%
                    {\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate -90>>}}%
            }%
            {}{}%
    \fi%
    \ifLuaTeX%
        \newcounter{cntsideways}%
        \AtBeginShipout{%
            \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{rotate\number\value{page}}{page}{0}=0%
                \PLS@RemoveRotate%
            \else%
                \ifnumodd{\thepage}{\PLS@AddRotate{90}}{\PLS@AddRotate{-90}}%
            \fi}%
        \patchcmd{\@xrotfloat}%
            {\begin{minipage}\textheight}%
            {\begin{minipage}\textheight\rotatesidewayslabel}%
            {}{}%
        \newcommand\rotatesidewayslabel{\stepcounter{cntsideways}%
        \zlabel{tmp\thecntsideways}\zlabel{rotate\zref@extractdefault{tmp\thecntsideways}{page}{0}}}%
    \fi%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-10]

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        Test
        \caption{Just an example figure.}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

    \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is that `\afterpage` works fine, but setting the pageattribute has to be delayed until TeX no longer works on the previous page.
Luckily, `\latelua` allows executing Lua code which is delayed to a proper moment, so you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\ifLuaTeX
    \edef\pdfpageattr{\pdfvariable pageattr}
\fi

\makeatletter
    \def\@PDFrot#1{%
        \ifXeTeX%
            \special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate #1>>}%
        \fi%
        \ifLuaTeX%
            \latelua{pdf.setpageattributes(string.gsub(pdf.getpageattributes() or '', '/Rotate [+-]?\csstring\%d+', '') .. '/Rotate #1')}%
            \afterpage{\directlua{pdf.setpageattributes((string.gsub(pdf.getpageattributes(), '/Rotate #1', '')))}}%
        \fi%
    }

    \patchcmd{\@xrotfloat}%
        {\begin{minipage}\textheight}%
        {\begin{minipage}\textheight\@PDFrot{90}}%
        {}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-10]

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        Test
        \caption{Just an example figure.}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

    \lipsum[1-5]


    \lipsum[1-10]

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        Test
        \caption{Just an example figure.}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

    \lipsum[1-5]


    \lipsum[1-10]

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        Test
        \caption{Just an example figure.}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

    \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the sidewaysfigure directly follow each other, one ends with multiply attributes in the pdf: `/Rotate 90/Rotate 90/Rotate 90`. (And there is a stray `ishow\@xrotfloat` in your code).

Comment: It looks as if for once afterpage is actually useful - I wonder what @DavidCarlisle  will say about this ;-).

Answer (score 0):

While [DigNative's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479815) for XeLaTeX works for the most part, I had some trouble with it. It turns out that `\thepage` expands to the page number as it is on the first run, which might not equal the page number in the final run. [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239452/thepage-give-wrong-number#239457) Specifically, I got different results based on whether I used `\clearpage` before the `sidewaysfigure` or not, or when I had multiple figures following each other.

To solve this, I went for an approach with `\label`+`\pageref`, similar to what Ulrike Fischer mentioned in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479812/extension-of-rotating-package-to-set-pdf-rotation#comment1212422_479812). One side note: because `\pageref` does not expand to a number but to text (which depends on the `\pagenumbering`, so it might not even *look* like a number), I had to use the `\getpagerefnumber` command from the `refcount` package. [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-to-use-pagereffoo-as-a-number#4212)

Note that I didn't update the LuaLaTeX part, that seems to work fine. But as I'm using XeLaTeX, I wanted to throw in this fix :)

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\makeatletter
    \ifXeTeX%
        \newcounter{rotfigcount}%
        \patchcmd{\@xrotfloat}%
            {\begin{minipage}\textheight}%
            {%
                \begin{minipage}\textheight%
                \stepcounter{rotfigcount}%
                \label{rotfig:\therotfigcount}%
                \ifnumodd{\getpagerefnumber{rotfig:\therotfigcount}}%
                    {\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate 90>>}}%
                    {\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate -90>>}}%
            }%
            {}{}%
    \fi%
    \ifLuaTeX%
        \newcounter{cntsideways}%
        \AtBeginShipout{%
            \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{rotate\number\value{page}}{page}{0}=0%
                \PLS@RemoveRotate%
            \else%
                \ifnumodd{\thepage}{\PLS@AddRotate{90}}{\PLS@AddRotate{-90}}%
            \fi}%
        \patchcmd{\@xrotfloat}%
            {\begin{minipage}\textheight}%
            {\begin{minipage}\textheight\rotatesidewayslabel}%
            {}{}%
        \newcommand\rotatesidewayslabel{\stepcounter{cntsideways}%
        \zlabel{tmp\thecntsideways}\zlabel{rotate\zref@extractdefault{tmp\thecntsideways}{page}{0}}}%
    \fi%
\makeatotherz

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-10]

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        Test
        \caption{Just an example figure.}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        Test 2
        \caption{Just a second example figure.}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

    \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```