# \thepage counter does not always work perfectly

Tags: labels, counters, page, pageref

I have a small problem that I can not solve, and I do not understand the cause.

`\thepage` counter is sometimes one page earlier than the actual page where it is invoked

I think it is because the text is formatted before being added to the output.

Here is a Minimal Working Example.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    right=1.2cm,
    left=1.8cm,
    top=1.8cm,
    bottom=1cm,
    paperwidth=110mm,
    paperheight=178mm
}


\newcommand\titre{%
\vspace{1em}%
{\centering%
AMAZING POEM\par%
}%
}


\begin{document}
\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\thepage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that at the top of pages 2, 3 and 4, `\thepage` shows 1, 2 and 3, instead of 2, 3 and 4.

It's even worse when you use `\\` instead of `obeylines` :

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    right=1.2cm,
    left=1.8cm,
    top=1.8cm,
    bottom=1cm,
    paperwidth=110mm,
    paperheight=178mm
}


\newcommand\titre{%
\vspace{1em}%
{\centering%
AMAZING POEM\par%
}%
}


\begin{document}
\titre{}
\begingroup
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
~\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
~\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
~\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
~\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\

\titre{}
\begingroup
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
~\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
~\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
~\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
~\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\thepage\\
I'm an amazing poem\\
\endgroup
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

I thank in advance the intelligent people who could explain me the reason of this problem.

Great thanks!

**EDIT**

Even with `\label` and `\pageref`, the problem is still here.

For example:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}


%pdfLaTeX
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    right=1.2cm,
    left=1.8cm,
    top=1.8cm,
    bottom=1cm,
    paperwidth=110mm,
    paperheight=178mm
}


\newcommand\titre{%
\vspace{1em}%
{\centering%
AMAZING POEM\par%
}%
}

\newcounter{nbrefpage}
\setcounter{nbrefpage}{0}
\newcommand\afficherpage{%
    \stepcounter{nbrefpage}%
    \def\tmpnbrefpage{\arabic{nbrefpage}testpage}%
    \label{\tmpnbrefpage}%
    \pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}%
}


\begin{document}
\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup
  
\end{document}
```

And the result (after 2 compilations of course) is the same:

[image]

In the `.aux` file, we see:

```
\newlabel{16testpage}{{}{1}}
```

instead of

```
\newlabel{16testpage}{{}{2}}
```

Comment: that is expected, you can only use `\thepage` where the page is known, eg in head and foot of a page style. use `\label` ad `\pageref` to refer to  page in the body

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, when I use `\label` and `\pageref`, I have the same problem. I don't understand why.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196033/how-do-i-test-for-a-new-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were allowing a page break between the `\label` and printing the number,adding a box keeps them together

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}


%pdfLaTeX
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    right=1.2cm,
    left=1.8cm,
    top=1.8cm,
    bottom=1cm,
    paperwidth=110mm,
    paperheight=178mm
}


\newcommand\titre{%
\vspace{1em}%
{\centering%
AMAZING POEM\par%
}%
}

\newcounter{nbrefpage}
\setcounter{nbrefpage}{0}
\newcommand\afficherpage{%
    \stepcounter{nbrefpage}%
    \def\tmpnbrefpage{\arabic{nbrefpage}testpage}%
    \mbox{\label{\tmpnbrefpage}%
    \pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}%
}


\begin{document}
\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup

\titre{}
\begingroup
\obeylines
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
~
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\afficherpage
I'm an amazing poem
\endgroup
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: David Carlisle, I am amazed! Thank you so much! But, I don't understand why "holding together" the label and the display of the labelpage, brings a different result.

Comment: I mean: why "pageref" changes the "label" in the ".aux"? "pageref" just gets the value displayed in the ".aux". Why, with an "mbox", does "label" change its value...?

Comment: I notice that it is enough to set `\mbox{\label{...}}` to obtain the good reference of page.

Comment: @PierreDufays yes but that requires more implementation details to see why it works, but  the version I used would work for any implemenentation of `\pageref` as boxes never break

Comment: @DavidCarliste yes I understand. But could you give me a reference, or a book, or a section of a book, which explains that aspect of LaTeX? It would be very interesting.